Next.js- dynamic import failed to load the component with a variable as module path
`We need to load the component with dynamic import
for eg: we have hello.js component in "component/shared/hello.js"
and we want to load the "hello" component in login component which is at "component/page/login"
`*const path = `components/shared/hello`;
    const DynamicComponent = dynamic(() => import(`${path}`), {
        ssr: false,
    });

return (
        <div>
            <DynamicComponent />
     </div>
    );*`

we got the error as "failed to load the component"
enter image description here
as shown below this map doesnt have requested component path so its throwing error,
then how do we load component with dynamic import with relative path
enter image description here

Instead of using dynamic import with a variable as the module path, use require with a string literal for the path, and include the full relative path to the component file.


const path = 'components/shared/hello'; // Use a string literal for the path

const DynamicComponent = dynamic(() => require(`../../${path}`).then(mod => mod.default), {
    ssr: false,
});

return (
    <div>
        <DynamicComponent />
    </div>
);



and instead of '../../' you can use on which level you have to reach the hello component.
